# ¿Como evitar dobles espacios en input html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quiero evitar esos molestos dobles espacios en algunos inputs, ¿tienen alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo? No creo tener problema con hacerlo totalmente en el lado del cliente.

Les dejo un ejemplo de uno de mis input:

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cliente">Cliente</label>
      <input type="text" name="cliente" class="form-control" id="cliente" placeholder="cliente">
 </div>
```

Comment: a que te refieres con dobles espacios ??

Comment: por favor reeplantea tu pregunta

Comment: se podria en un div de contenteditable

Comment: Al presionar dos veces la tecla de espacio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solucion que daria seria verificando la ultima tecla escrita, si la ultima tecla es espacio tendriamos que denegar la escritura al segundo espacio con `event.preventDefault();`

```js
document.getElementById("text").addEventListener("keydown", teclear);

var flag = false;
var teclaAnterior = "";

function teclear(event) {
  teclaAnterior = teclaAnterior + " " + event.keyCode;
  var arregloTA = teclaAnterior.split(" ");
  if (event.keyCode == 32 && arregloTA[arregloTA.length - 2] == 32) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text"></input>
```

Comment: Funciona sin ningun problema!